# Project file structure change and Git

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a regular repo with only master.

I have been making commits ...

I needed to restructure the file paths of the entire project.

I commited the file path changes as normal.

How do I make the repo only show the new file structure. When I look at the repo I can see the files showing in both the old location and the new location?

Or should I just leave as-is?

Comment: I recommend to you to create a new repo and do push, and then delete the old-same repo, It happened to me and seems the best way...

Comment: How do you look at the repo and see the files in both locations?

Comment: @M.Mariscal `git push` sends the entire project history to the new repo, making it identical with the old one. It doesn't help.

Comment: For example, inside Bitbucket, I can see the file structure showing the initial commit with for example foo.html and then I recently in the last commit moved foo.html to a new folder called "FolderA". So I can see initial commit showing in / the foo.html and now also under /FolderA/foo.html with the recent commit. But on my local development system the local repo shows correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you could try "git tag old_master; git checkout --orphan -B master "

then the old commit chain with the old file structure is still accessible from the tag 'old_master' if you need it.  But only the new file structure will be on the new 'master' branch. As an orphan commit, it has no parents, and so starts a new commit chain.

Comment: git tag old_master master
git branch -D master
git checkout --orphan master

Comment: git tag old_master master
   git branch -D master
   git checkout --orphan master